# How to handle multiple Jquery + Ajax dependent select boxes in the same form

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I can't figure out how to handle having more than one row of chained select boxes in a form using jquery and ajax.

There are plenty of tutorials available explaining how to create a single instance of chained selects, but unfortunately (for me, at least) they never discuss how to handle more than one instance/row of chained selects in the form.

I can get it working by explicitly writing different blocks of jquery code, as shown below,  but my problem is that there can be any number of rows of chained selects that will be generated automatically.

To handle this, I need a single block of jquery code that can work on all of the rows of chained selects. Everything I've tried so far results in the typical newbie problem of not being able to get any of the rows of chained select boxes working other than the first one.

Here is the html:

```
<form>
    Connection Type :
    <select name="contype_01" id="contype_01">
      <option value="ssh">SSH</option>
      <option value="telnet">Telnet</option>
    </select>

    Credentials :
    <select name="creds_01" id="creds_01">
      <option> --Please Select-- </option>
    </select>

    <br /> <!-- 2nd row of chained selects -->

    Connection Type :
    <select name="contype_02" id="contype_02">
      <option value="ssh">SSH</option>
      <option value="telnet">Telnet</option>
    </select>

    Credentials :
    <select name="creds_02" id="creds_02">
      <option> --Please Select-- </option>
    </select>
  </form>
```

And the jquery:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){

    $("#contype_01").change(function(){
        var contype=$("#contype_01").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"ncmexport-helper.php",
            data:"contype="+contype,
            success:function(data){
                $("#creds_01").html(data);
            }
        });
    });

    $("#contype_02").change(function(){
        var contype=$("#contype_02").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"post",
            url:"ncmexport-helper.php",
            data:"contype="+contype,
            success:function(data){
                $("#creds_02").html(data);
            }
        });
    });


});
```

If you've made it this far I thank you, and here is my question: What do I need to do to turn the two blocks of jquery code shown above into a single block that can work with multiple chained selects in a form? My very limited javascript and jquery skills are not yet sufficient enough for me to know how to iterate over the different select box id's.

Note: the original jquery / ajax code I'm using came from this tutorial:
http://phpseason.wordpress.com/2013/02/19/dynamic-dependent-select-box-using-jquery-and-ajax/

Comment: So this code is from a tutorial. Can you give us YOUR code (at least the HTML) of what you want to do? How many option boxes? how many are chained? It seems to be better to give us your specific problem with the code that you have written.

Comment: That pretty much is my code. The only thing not shown is the php script that feeds the data to the 2nd select box (the one that depends on the value selected in the first). There are only two select boxes per row. As shown, everything works. My specific problem is that I haven't been able to figure out how bind the change handler to all of the selects (as mentioned below by jj689).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can tell, you should bind your change handler to all the contype selects ( e.g. using a class selector ).

e.g.

```
<form>
Connection Type :
<select name="contype_01" id="contype_01" class="contype">
  <option value="ssh">SSH</option>
  <option value="telnet">Telnet</option>
</select>

Credentials :
<select name="creds_01" id="creds_01">
  <option> --Please Select-- </option>
</select>

<br /> <!-- 2nd row of chained selects -->

Connection Type :
<select name="contype_02" id="contype_02" class="contype">
  <option value="ssh">SSH</option>
  <option value="telnet">Telnet</option>
</select>

Credentials :
<select name="creds_02" id="creds_02">
  <option> --Please Select-- </option>
</select>
```

js:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".contype").change(function(){
       var element = $(this);
       var contype = element.val();          
       $.ajax({
           type:"post",
           url:"ncmexport-helper.php",
           data:"contype=" + contype,
           success:function(data){
               // build the id for creds
               var id = element.attr("id");
               var credId = "#creds_" + id.slice(-2);
               $(credId).html(data);
           }
       });
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks very much like the sort of thing I need. For the moment the 2nd select boxes are not showing the value returned from the php helper script. I will do some more troubleshooting tomorrow morning.

Comment: The chained selects are still not being populated. On the js console I see that id is not defined in the line: 
var credId = "#creds_" + id.slice(-2);

Any ideas? Note: My php helper script simply echoes an <option>bla bla</option> line when it receives the ajax request, and that part is working fine. This is what is supposed to appear in the chained select dropdown.

Comment: Sorry my mistake I should not have used $(this) inside the success callback. I've updated the answer to reflect this.

Comment: Success! Thank you very much! I'm sure this will be of use to others too, as it isn't easy to find any working examples of this.  And don't worry about the questionable use of credentials. This is not what the final application will be doing.